# CodeMirror: How can i refresh not all editor but only one line?

Tags: codemirror

Can `CodeMirror` somehow refresh using `refresh()` function not all the *`textarea`* but only one specific line in it?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, but you could write a function like this that has the same effect:

`function touchLine(cm, lineNo) {
  cm.operation(function() {
    cm.replaceRange(" ", {line: lineNo, ch: 0});
    cm.replaceRange("", {line: lineNo, ch: 0}, {line: lineNo, ch: 1});
  });
}`